# No .htacess file in my pub/static folder

Tags: magento2

I've received built website to continue working on. sometimes I got some unexpected behavior, So I decided to delete content of `pub/static` folder and deploy it again. When I opened it I didn't find .htaccess file inside it and storefront has no problem.

How can `pub/static` folder doesn't contain `.htaccess` and there is no problem.

Comment: it could be hidden and enabling to see hidden files will allow it to be seen or visible.

Comment: No, it's not hidden

Comment: Which OS you are using ?

Comment: @Pawan centos 7

Comment: Files with . Hide by default. You can see them by press `ctrl+h`. You deleted by mistake.

Comment: it's not hidden, So if it's deleted, how there is no problem in storefront without it?

Answer (score 0):

You already mentioned ***I decided to delete pub/static folder and deploy it again***, that means you deleted **.htaccess** too. Don't do this. You need to delete content inside **pub/static** folder except **.htaccess**.

Now the solution is: create new **.htaccess** inside **pub/static** and add content from default m2 instance that you use.

Comment: I cannot fund .htaccess before deleting.

Comment: This is a hidden file. If not found then somehow deleted. Now add it.

Comment: it's not hidden, So if it's deleted, how there is no problem in storefront without it?

Comment: Did you disabled deployed_version.txt?

Comment: Downvote is not a solution to your problem. This is too bad.

Comment: No, I didn't disabled deployed_version.txt and I didn't downvote your answer at all. Thank you for trying to help me